# Query related to No.of samples in summary report of jmeter

Tags: jmeter, report, sample, summary

**Number of Threads (users)**: 10
**Ramp-up Period (in seconds)**: 1
**Loop Count** : 2

*Result* - **When I ran the test it shows 40 samples rather expected count was 20 .**
I want to ask what could be the reason behind 40 samples .

Number of Threads (users): 10
Ramp-up Period (in seconds): 1
Loop Count : 1

*Result* - **When I ran the test it shows  20 samples rather expected count was 10 .**

**Error** - *I tried to compute but I can't understand how it is doubling the user count every time*

Comment: Can you post your test plan?

Comment: where does it show number of samples? do you refer to some listener?

Comment: I have used:                                                                                                                                                           HTTP Requests Default                                                                                   Thread Group                                                                                               Cookie Manager                                                                                           View Result Tree, Summary Report,Response Time Graph

Answer (score 0):

It just means that every your thread sends 2 requests instead of 1 expected. If you use HTTP Request sampler, then I can bet that you have "Follow Redirects" option enabled and send requests to resource that answers with 3xx response code.
Adding some listeners like View Results in Tree/Table to your Test Plan (on debugging phase at least) would be a good idea. It really helps to check what exactly Jmeter sends/receives.

UPDATE:
Response with [301 response code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) is a recommendation for your client (browser, jmeter, etc) to move to resource defined by "Location: " response header. So, all popular browsers (and Jmeter by default) automatically forward to this location. That's exactly your "doubled" request. If responses with 301 code is really your case, then you can do one of two things: 1. Disable "Follow Redirects" checkbox that displayed in Jmeter HTTP Request sampler settings right under the input where you enter Path:
[image: Follow Redirects checkbox]

But in this case you'll request not the destination page that originally displayed for this URL in your browser, because 301 responses don't contain body, only headers.

2. Request not the original URL that answers with 301 code but the final location instead (check your response headers and find the value in Location header).

2nd option is better (by my mind) as it produces a load to an object you really expect. But, of course, it depends on your goals.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Can you plaese elaborate what is difference between 3xx reponse code and other response code...??                                  1 more thing what should i do to avoid this and get exact samples not double.                                                                                                            2 thing where is thsi "Follow Redirects" present.?

Comment: Thanks a lot .:)                                                                                                I am sorry i am new in jmeter.I have 1 query .                                                                   **Request not the original URL that answers with 301 code but the final location instead (check your response headers and find the value in Location header).**                                                                                    Can you please elaborate what this means .I am getting 302 code.

Comment: I am getting this in View listener
Sample Start: 2016-02-10 19:30:08 IST
Load time: 206
Latency: 206
Size in bytes: 301
Headers size in bytes: 301
Body size in bytes: 0
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 0
Response code: 302
Response message: Found

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=8BD07E2F66DB29210C944D0114730C50; Path=/myadvantage.apac/; HttpOnly
Location: http://10.234.83.161:8080/myadvantage.test/login_page
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 0
HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: text/html;charset=UTF-8
DataEncoding: UTF-8

Comment: The data you provided shows that you send requests to something like 10.234.83.161:8080/, but your server forwards you to login page instead: "Location: 10.234.83.161:8080/myadvantage.test/login_page". So, just change path in your sample to /myadvantage.test/login_page. It should solve your issue with doubled counters.