# Jmeter HTTP sample HTML report generation

Tags: http, jmeter

I am trying to generate html reports for a simple test where i do a HTTP GET which involves a 302 Redirect. The stats generated is bit confusing where it shows 3 different HTTP requests as below.
[Jmeter statistics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axGnW.jpg)

I am using 3000 thread and i see i am getting almost 9000 samples. I assume there can be two HTTP requests 1. The original one and 2. the Redirect following. But why i am getting 3 HTTP requests. Am i missing some thing.
I am using the following to run and generate report:
jmeter.sh -n -t  -l 
jmeter.sh -g  -o ./analysis

The report is fairly straight forward if redirects are not involved though.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35201923/query-related-to-no-of-samples-in-summary-report-of-jmeter

Answer (score 0):

They may stand for:

- [Redirects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection) (HTTP Statuses 3xx). In this case you should cross-check JMeter's behaviour with real browser's network footprint. You can see which requests browser is sending using [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools). If the number matches - you should be good to go as you're properly simulating real browser's behaviour. If not - play with `Redirect Automatically` and `Follow Redirects` checkboxes in the HTTP Request sampler:

  [image]
- [Embedded Resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses/) (images, scripts, styles, fonts, sounds, etc.). This is pretty normal as downloading resources is what real browsers do. Just make sure to add [HTTP Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) to your Test Plan as real browsers request these items only once and make sure that no external resources are in scope (coming from CDNs or 3rd-party services) as you should not include external services into the scope of your load test

Comment: Thank you .I made a mistake in my original question where i said 3000 requests and getting 6000 samples in report. It should be 9000 sample in report. I was in the assumption that Jmeter report generation is not working as expected For my test Jmeter is summing  1.HTTP Request 2. HTTP Request 0(which gets 302) 3. HTTP Request 1(REdirect follow)  and says 9000 Samples. I believe the result against the row HTTP Request is the right one. Am i missing anything while interpreting the results

Comment: Response time for `HTTP Request` is the sum of `HTTP Request-0` and `HTTP Request-1` so if you're looking for a total request execution time - you should be looking at `HTTP Request` only. If you don't want to be confused with these request "children" you can add the next line to *user.properties* file: `jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=false` and JMeter will stop storing these main request children. Another option is  the request(s) which cumulative time you want to measure under the [Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller/)